# Submenu dissappears on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the dropdown menu behave like here: https://svyaznoy.ru

```js
var timer;
$(".catalog-menu li").mouseenter(function() {
    var that = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(that).children(".submenu").show();
    }, 500);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var that = this;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(that).children(".submenu").hide();
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

li.submenu-item {
  min-width: 110px;
}

ul.catalog-menu {
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="catalog-menu">
  <li>
    <span>Apple</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item">
      <span>Laptops</span>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item">Macbook 12</li>
        <li class="submenu-item">Macbook Pro 13</li>
         <li class="submenu-item">Macbook Pro 15</li>
         <li class="submenu-item">Macbook Air Retina</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="submenu-item">
        <span>iPhones</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone 8</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone 8 Plus</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone X</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone XS</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone XS Max</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Samsung</li>
  <li>Xiaomi</li>
</ul>
```

It works somewhat similar to svyaznoy.ru, but have a bug. 
For example, I hover on "Apple" menu item. Laptops and iPhones show up. Next I hover on "Laptops". Some apple laptop models show up. And here's where the bug shows: if my mouse pointer doesn't leave "Laptops" item and goes straight to laptops submenu - all is ok, but when it leaves "Laptops" on the way to laptops list, e.g. it hovers on iPhones for a moment, then laptops list hides, and I want it to stay there. How can I fix this bug?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16region/vtrj9wgk/30/

Comment: if you not fix the fiddle meanwhile i suggest to clean your testbrowser cache :) Works like it should.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig no, its not. Open the fiddle, hover on "Apple". Then hover on Laptops, then go to laptops list but make it so your mouse pointer hovers "iPhones". Then you will see the bug I'm talking about.

Comment: Me too. I don't see whats the problem. Can you make a gif ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `display: none` to `visibility: hidden` and add `transition-delay`. And so you wont need jquery/js

```css
ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    
    ul.submenu {
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: 1px;
      margin-left: -1px;
      transition: 0s visibility;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    
    li {
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
    li:hover > ul.submenu {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    li.submenu-item {
      min-width: 110px;
    }
    
    ul.catalog-menu {
      width: 150px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="catalog-menu">
  <li>
    <span>Apple</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item">
      <span>Laptops</span>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item">Macbook 12</li>
        <li class="submenu-item">Macbook Pro 13</li>
         <li class="submenu-item">Macbook Pro 15</li>
         <li class="submenu-item">Macbook Air Retina</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="submenu-item">
        <span>iPhones</span>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone 8</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone 8 Plus</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone X</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone XS</li>
          <li class="submenu-item">iPhone XS Max</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Samsung</li>
  <li>Xiaomi</li>
</ul>
```